# Accessing inputs of a third-party component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I use a third-party component which is basically a set of two inputs with some logic inside. Now I need to set a focus on one of the inputs.

I'm trying to extend the component-class and access the inputs inside of the componentDidMount:

```
const Widget = require('widget')

class MyClass exteds Widget {
  componentDidMOunt() {
    this.refs // this is {}
    // how can I access inputs here?
  }
}
```

NB: I don't have access to widget internals. I can  use it only as is